# Upload pdf file in google docs

Tags: google-docs

I'm working on uploading fiels to google docs using c#,its working fine with text file and word file.But when i try to get upload PDF and EXCEL files am getting bad request error.

Am using SSO concept for google login with asp.net c#.

Can anyone help me to upload pdf and excel files?

Thanks in advance...

Ranjithkumar.C

Comment: You don't need to add signature in your post - your user card is added automatically. Just fill in your profile.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using the deprecated Documents List API. Use the new Google Drive SDK v2 instead. The insert function allows you to upload files of any type:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

OAuth authorization is described at:

https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials